# Why do coloured planes start to turn white when they're made semi-transparent?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, transparency

I want to do an [octant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octant_(solid_geometry)) with semi-transparent panels with drawings on them. I achieved part of the desired effect, but the drawing is almost invisible against the white background, or when the other panels are semi-transparent too. I'm using "Blender Render" as the render engine.

Drawing visible when there is no transparency.

[image: opaque octant]

Drawing barely visible with the red panel semi-transparent (alpha 0.5).

[image: red panel semitransparent]

Drawing almost invisible when all three panels are semi-transparent.

[image: three panels semitransparent]

I'd like to have the panels semi-transparent (still showing their colors, but the image not so transparent). I think 0.5 alpha should give me a #808080 gray for the drawing, why is it becoming so white?

Comment: Please mention which render engine you're using.

Comment: @RayMairlot Thank you, I added the engine to the end of the question.

Comment: What color is your background?

Comment: @Dontwalk World: Horizon Color is set to white, which is what appears in the background on the images above. Also, those images are print-screens, since no file is being generated, despite there's a full path + filename in the Output of the Render options.